# I'm trying to find international obesity prevalence by year

Tags: data-request, medical

I'm trying to find international obesity prevalence by year.  Does anyone have a source at the country level?

Answer (score 3):

Here are two potential sources for you:

- http://www.worldobesity.org/aboutobesity/world-map-obesity/ has an interactive map and from that I found some endpoints:

  - http://www.worldobesity.org/maps/adults/data.json and http://www.worldobesity.org/maps/children/data.json
  - for more detailed data by country, you can hit http://www.worldobesity.org/maps/ajax/1/UK and http://www.worldobesity.org/maps/ajax/1/US
- https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/2228rank.html is the CIA Factbook which I  bet many people have created scrapers and APIs for