# Looking for US percentage of population overweight or obese over last 50 years

Tags: data-request, government

I've seen other charts that reference data from the CDC, but I haven't found anything useful on their site, and they don't return emails.

Thoughts?

Comment: are any of these answers useful? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/5256/1511

Comment: Unfortunately looks like the links are mostly dead...

Comment: Wikipedia pointed me to https://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/health-statistics/overweight-obesity which has a graph, and the references section seems to have at least some data to support those graphs. Goes back to 1960.

Answer (score 2):

Only a small time slice, but you can get since 2000 for every country from [FAO](http://www.fao.org/faostat).

Suite of Food Security Indicators --> http://www.fao.org/faostat/en/#data/FS

Select: United States

Select: 
[image]

Select: "All years"

Click "Download Data" (or [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/fjHX6Wdz))

Preview:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you work you put into this. At this point I really need to get data going back at least 50 years, or as long as I can get it. I may try to contact CDC using a few more other means, they also have a phone number listed so maybe I'll try that. Thanks again.